# Target class [auth.shop] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, shopify

I am Trying to Create My First Shopify App Using Laravel, But I am Stuck in this error.

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [auth.shop] does not exist.
```

my web.php file is like that:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->middleware(['auth.shop'])->name('home');
```

and the version is

```
"osiset/laravel-shopify": "^17.1"
```

Someone could help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this issue https://github.com/osiset/laravel-shopify/issues/503

`auth.shopify` is the `v11+` package middleware.

If you are using `v10` then its `auth.shop`

As per latest Release https://github.com/osiset/laravel-shopify/releases/tag/v17.0.0

> Removal of auth.shopify middleware in-favour of verify.shopify
> middleware

So you should use `verify.shopify` instead of `auth.shop`

[image]

Also as per documentation https://github.com/osiset/laravel-shopify/wiki/Installation#middlewares

> verify.shopify, handles authentication of the shop, verification, and
> session token handling for both standard requests and AJAX.
> auth.webhook, handles verification of webhooks and their data.
> auth.proxy, handles verification of proxy requests.